# How to grant MySQL user privilege to "SHOW TABLES"

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have two MySQL databases hosted on my website, one for a MyBB forum and the other for data displayed on the website that comes from Raspberry Pis. The MyBB database has a user associated with it, and I've created another MySQL user to associate with the other database and granted it all privileges in cPanel.

When I connect to the database on the Raspberry Pi, I am able to use most SQL commands (INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, etc.) and they work fine. However, the command "SHOW TABLES" gives an "access denied" error for the MySQL user.

I tried deleting the database and repopulating it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: What `GRANTs` does that user have?

Answer (score 1):

From the official [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-databases.html), You see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global `SHOW DATABASES` privilege.

Check the grants for the connected user. To check grants:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR root(user);
```

For example, if you wish grant `SELECT` privileges to a user, login as `root` (user with `grant privilege`) and issue the following command statement.

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* to 'user'@'host';
```

Also, from the same document, you can use the [mysqlshow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlshow.html) command to display database and table information.

I hope this answer will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was actually that I had the database name formatted into the SHOW TABLES query surrounded by single quotes. When I removed the single quotes, the query started working fine. Apparently, SHOW TABLES does not accept single quotes like the other SQL commands do.

Comment: I was confusing backticks with single quotes. I forgot that mogrify inserts single quotes, and the database name needs to be surrounded by backticks instead.